# The specified type was not recognized

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

Error:

> {"The specified type was not recognized: name='VitalsPlugin',
>   namespace='', at ."}

Code:

```
public class SimpleSerializer
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string xml = "<Plugin xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:type=\"VitalsPlugin\" ID=\"eaded5f3-7019-47b9-8f9f-e7c1879774f4\"><CopyForwardChecked>true</CopyForwardChecked></Plugin>";
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);
        var result = Deserialize(reader);
    }

    static Plugin Deserialize(TextReader xml)
    {
        XmlSerializer xsr = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Plugin), new Type[] {typeof(VitalsPlugin)});
        Plugin result = xsr.Deserialize(xml) as Plugin;

        return result;
    }
}
```

Other useful code:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(VitalsPlugin))]
public class Plugin
{
}

public class VitalsPlugin
{
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After much tinkering I ran across a [definition](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/adiehelp/v5r1m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.xmlbuilder.doc/topics/txsityp.html) of `xsi:type`.  After reading the definition I realized that this type specifies a deriving class.  I updated the code to

```
public class VitalsPlugin: Plugin
{
}
```

and it works.